# Huawei broadband modem internet connection using wine

Tags: wine, huawei

I have installed the Huawei mobile broadband software using wine but when I connect the huawei usb modem, the wine application cannot see it. What do I need to do to configure it in wine?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use windows drivers with wine in Ubuntu. What is  the model number? Just plug in the modem & follow these [steps for 3G on help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-help/net-mobile.html).

If it does not work, then open terminal( <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>) write this commands (modem still plugged in)

```
lsusb
usb-devices
```